# Is there any amount limitation for Authorize.net eCheck transaction?

Tags: authorize.net

Can anyone please tell me whether there any amount limitation for Authorize.net eCheck transaction? I am asking this for live account for sandbox it is $100.

Answer (score 1):

For testing purposes, eCheck transactions over $100 are declined for testing purposes.  Check the testing guide for more details.

https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/

Comment: Yes that I know.I wanted to know about the live account

Comment: @AparajitaSinha Transaction limits for a live account are set during underwriting and are controlled at the gateway.  There is no API to determine these amounts, but should be known to the merchant.

Comment: The testing guide at that URL only has information about credit cards. Not a single word about eChecks.